# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just copied and pasted code from tutorial in my file models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title

  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

and am getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: /home/row/blog/app/models/post.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or '\n'
  ...idates :name,  :presence => true
...                               ^
```

I made some changes in the code like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title

  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

But the same error appears. I am confused.

Comment: It's odd how it says that that code is on line one. I am wondering if it isn't seeing the line endings. Do you know what line endings you're using?

Comment: @Ross yeah, thank you. I used "Mac OS 9" line ending in unix machine.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Would you mind if I posted as an answer so you could accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the wrong line endings. Try changing them to be UNIX line endings.